# XStream derserialization makes all objects same

Tags: java, xstream, objectinputstream

I have a custom method that reads a XML file and creates a number of objects.

Method code:

```
    public static Property[] initProperties() {
    Property p1, p2;
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("Property", Property.class);
    xstream.registerConverter(new PropsConverter());
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = xstream.createObjectInputStream(Utils.class.getResourceAsStream("Properties.xml"));             
        p1 = (Property) in.readObject();
        System.out.println("P1_"+p1.getName());
        p2 = (Property) in.readObject();
        System.out.println("P2_"+p2.getName());
        Property[] array = {p1,p2};
        return array;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The custom converter has `System.Out.Println` built into every step so I can see if the converter reads stuff right. IT DOES. I have this XML file

```
<root>
<Property>
  <name>Property 1</name>
  <ownedBy>NULL</ownedBy>
  <price>1000</price>
</Property>
<Property>
  <name>Test2</name>
  <ownedBy>NULL</ownedBy>
  <price>1000</price>
</Property>
</root>
```

And the converter spits both out right. When I call the `initProperties()` function in another class to fill a new array I get an issue.

Main Class

```
        try {
        Properties[] availableProperties = Utils.initProperties();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now Unless I am completely mistaken `System.out.println(availableProperties[0].getName());` should print Property 1 and `System.out.println(availableProperties[1].getName());` should print Test 2.

I however get two lines of:

Test 2
Test 2

Why?

The custom Converter

public class PropsConverter implements Converter {

```
public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
    return clazz.equals(Property.class);
}

public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
        MarshallingContext context) {
    Property props = (Property) value;
    writer.startNode("name");
    writer.setValue(props.getName());
    writer.endNode();
    writer.startNode("ownedBy");
    writer.setValue(props.getName());
    writer.endNode();
    writer.startNode("price");
    writer.setValue(props.getPriceAsString());
    writer.endNode();
}

public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
        UnmarshallingContext context) {
    Property props = new Property();
    reader.moveDown();
    props.setName(reader.getValue());
//        System.out.println("NAME_" + reader.getValue());
    reader.moveUp();
    reader.moveDown();
    props.setOwnedBy(reader.getValue());
//        System.out.println("OWNEDBY_" + reader.getValue());
    reader.moveUp();
    reader.moveDown();
    props.setPrice(Float.parseFloat(reader.getValue()));
 //        System.out.println("PRICE_" + reader.getValue());
    reader.moveUp();
    return props;
}
}
```

Comment: The custom converter probably reuses the same object for every conversion. Show us the code.

Comment: it is up. Does it help?

Comment: The fields in Property are not static, are they?

Comment: yes they are. otherwise the setters give an error saying that the non-static field cannot be referenced

Comment: Never mind. I changed all the Property fields to non-static and the setters to this.name = name from Properties.name = name and it all works. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can check it and give karma?